# Swift UIAlertController Getting Text Field Text

Tags: xcode, swift, uialertcontroller

I need to get the text from the text fields in my alert view when the Input button is pressed.

```
func inputMsg() {

    var points = ""
    var outOf = ""

    var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Input View", message: "Please Input Your Grade", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let actionCancle = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancle", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { ACTION in

        println("Cacle")
    }
    let actionInput = UIAlertAction(title: "Input", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { ACTION in

        println("Input")
        println(points)
        println(outOf)
    }

    alertController.addAction(actionCancle)
    alertController.addAction(actionInput)
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(txtField: UITextField!) in
        txtField.placeholder = "I got"
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        points = txtField.text
        })



    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(txtField: UITextField!) in
        txtField.placeholder = "Out Of"
        txtField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        outOf = txtField.text
    })
    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UIAlertController has a `textFields` property. That's its text fields. Any of your handlers can examine it and thus can get the text from any of the text fields.

Comment: How would you do what? I've told you everything there is to know. The alert controller is `alertController`. Its text fields are `textFields`. Their text is their `text`. You've created an input button and you've given it an action handler which will run when the Input button is pressed, and you've already put logging messages into it to prove it. It doesn't get any simpler than this.

Comment: @Unome do not deface my post with code that I didn't write. I _purposely_ did not provide code. If you want to add your own answer with code, feel free to do so! That is perfectly legal and is much better Stack Overflow behavior than trying to mess with someone else's answer. And it has many benefits for you: Your answer can get upvoted; the OP might even uncheck my answer and check yours!

Comment: @matt, sorry. Your answer was correct and it helped me solve the problem. I simply added an implementation example as **requested** in the comments.

Comment: @Unome No need to apologize; Stack Overflow takes some getting used to. Seriously, I invite you to add your own answer with your own code. But what I do _not_ condone is your putting words in my mouth.

Comment: @matt separate post added

Answer (score 8):

As **requested** here is an implementation solution.

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            if let textField = alertController.textFields?.first as? UITextField{
                println(textField.text)
            }
        }))
```

As stated above, the alertController has a property called `textFields`. You can conditionally unwrap that property to safely access a text field if you have added one. In this case since there is only one text field I just did the unwrap using the `first` property. Hope it helps.